# htaccess redirect not allowed ips

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have

```
<Files ads.php> 
order deny,allow
allow from 46.36.64.0/19
allow from 62.80.224.0/19
allow from 62.128.113.0/27
allow from 62.128.113.32/30
allow from 62.128.113.36/31
allow from 62.128.113.40/30
allow from 62.128.113.48/26
allow from 62.128.113.112/27
allow from 62.128.113.144/29
allow from 62.212.192.0/19
allow from 66.115.179.130/25
allow from 72.32.219.72/29
allow from 77.70.156.0/22
allow from 77.70.160.0/23
allow from 77.70.168.0/23
allow from 77.70.171.0/21
allow from 77.70.179.0/22
allow from 77.70.183.0/24
allow from 77.70.192.0/18
allow from 77.75.40.0/21
allow from 77.79.0.0/18
allow from 77.87.8.0/21
allow from 77.90.64.0/18
allow from 77.94.32.0/26
allow from 77.94.32.64/30
allow from 77.94.32.68/32
allow from 77.94.32.70/26
allow from 77.94.32.134/27
allow from 77.94.32.166/30
allow from 77.94.32.170/31
allow from 77.94.32.174/24
allow from 77.94.33.174/26
allow from 77.94.33.238/28
allow from 77.94.33.254/31
allow from 77.94.35.0/24
deny from all
</Files>
```

in my htaccess file, I need to redirect everyone whos ip is denied to index.php. How could I do it without rewriting IP's manually into tons of different rules? Is there any htaccess rule, like "if denied redirect to.." ?

Comment: [`ErrorDocument 403 index.php`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Comment: That' s actually not a redirect...

Comment: @ChristianGärtner its an internal redirect and would work just fine in this case.

Comment: errordocument not working, i placed it right before <Files ads.php>

Comment: @MindaugasJakubauskas have you blocked your IP to test ? I tested it and worked just fine.

Comment: I had to put a slash before index.php, I forgot that, everything works fine, thanks.